# Lookup find matching FileId

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

A brief overview, not including every detail of what I am trying to do is that I want to lookup all values in a row and return the file ID where the filename matches my search value not including the file extension. The full details are below.

My search values column is the column with the header value “SKU”. My destination column for all matched values is the column with the header “Primary Image Link”. I need to search all filenames in a folder “1BC_hajJ77Uvu_JLLEOnwkyf1ZCd5zrDs” and where the search value matches the filename not including the extension, return the file id in the destination column in the following format "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + FILEID +"view?usp=sharing". If the value is not found it should return “No Image”.

I have tried numerous versions of the script below and get no matches. Here is a link to a [test workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uYH7_Q2Sp8RW3gLD0XN8pXJvTt8p_1l9GptPqxJO66o/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function VlookupID() {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = wb.getSheetByName("Database");

  var headerRow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var skuIndex = headerRow.indexOf("SKU") + 1;
  var imageIndex = headerRow.indexOf("Primary Image Link") + 1;

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1BC_hajJ77Uvu_JLLEOnwkyf1ZCd5zrDs');
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name', 'Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var row = [];
    row.push(file.getName().split("."), "image(\"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId() + "\")");
    list.push(row);
  }

  const searchValues = sheet.getRange(2, skuIndex, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  const lookupValues = list.slice(1); // Exclude header row

  const matchSku = searchValues.map(searchRow => {
    const matchRow = lookupValues.find(r => r[0] == searchRow[0]);
    return matchRow ? [matchRow[1]] : ["No Image"];
  });
  sheet.getRange(2, imageIndex, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValues(matchSku);
}
```

Just in case it helps. I was previously using the following script to get the list of all files and ID's on a sheet and then using a vlookup to get the file link. I'm just trying to cut out the step of putting all of the lookup values in my sheet.

```
function PhotosList(){ 
  var wb     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh     = wb.getSheetByName('Photos');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1BC_hajJ77Uvu_JLLEOnwkyf1ZCd5zrDs'); 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName().split("."),"image(\"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId() +"\")")
    list.push(row);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
function ImageLookup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database"); // Replace with your sheet name
  var column = 1; // Column A (1-based index)
  var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Exclude header row
  var dstheader = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].indexOf("Primary Image Link")+1; 

  // Specify the folder ID where your files are located
  var folderId = "1BC_hajJ77Uvu_JLLEOnwkyf1ZCd5zrDs"; // Replace with your folder ID

  // Get all files in the specified folder
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

  // Create an object to store filenames (without extensions) as keys
  var filenames = {};
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    var filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, ""); // Remove file extension
    filenames[filenameWithoutExtension] = file.getId(); // Store file ID
  }

  // Iterate through column values and check if they match any filenames
  for (var i = 0; i < columnValues.length; i++) {
    var value = columnValues[i][0]; // Assuming single-column data
    if (filenames[value]) {
      // Set the file ID as a Google Drive link in the second column (B)
      var fileId = filenames[value];
      var driveLink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + fileId + "/view?usp=sharing";
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, dstheader).setValue(driveLink);
    } else {
      // No match found, set value to "No Image"
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, dstheader).setValue("No Image");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code. Please try this function and it will get the values as you need and will populate it in sheet.

```
function updateImageLinks() {
  var folderId = "1BC_hajJ77Uvu_JLLEOnwkyf1ZCd5zrDs"; // Folder ID
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var skuColumnIndex = values[0].indexOf("SKU") + 1; // Assuming the header is in the first row
  var imageLinkColumnIndex = values[0].indexOf("Primary Image Link") + 1; // Assuming the header is in the first row
  
  // Get file names and URLs in a separate sheet
  var fileSheet = getFileNamesAndUrls(folderId);
  var fileValues = fileSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // Loop through each row in the sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var sku = values[i][skuColumnIndex - 1];
    var fileId = findFileIdBySku(sku, fileValues);
    if (fileId) {
      var imageUrl = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + fileId + "/view?usp=sharing";
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, imageLinkColumnIndex).setValue(imageUrl);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, imageLinkColumnIndex).setValue("No Image");
    }
  }
}

function getFileNamesAndUrls(folderId) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fileSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("FilesDetails")
  fileSheet = fileSheet ? fileSheet : spreadsheet.insertSheet().setName("FilesDetails");
  
  // Set headers
  fileSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("File Name");
  fileSheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue("File ID");
  
  var row = 2;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    fileSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(fileName);
    fileSheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(fileId);
    row++;
  }
  
  return fileSheet;
}

function findFileIdBySku(sku, fileValues) {
  
  for (var i = 1; i < fileValues.length; i++) {
    var fileName = fileValues[i][0];
    var fileId = fileValues[i][1];
    if (fileName.split(".")[0] === sku) {
      return fileId;
    }
  }
  
  return null;
}
```

Comment: The updateImageLinks() has been running for about 20 minutes. Nothing yet.

Comment: Can you tell me 1) how many rows do you have in sheet? 2) How many files in folder?

Comment: To optimize it, you can first get the names and URLs of all the files in the folder in a sheet. And then compare the SKUs with the names in that sheet.

Comment: The data has 5,034 rows, there are currently 9,534 Files in the folder.

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer with optimized code. This would first get the file names and ids in another sheet and then use that sheet for comparision with skus. Please try this and let me know how much time it takes. Hopefully, this should complete within 30 mins. I would also recommend  adding console.log statements in your code - before, within and after the loops. This will help us understand where the time is consumed most to further optimize if needed.

Comment: Thank you. Testing now. As the PhotoList script takes about 1.5 minutes to write all the filenames without extensions and ID to a sheet and a vlookup script should take about 2-3 minutes perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way. I thought I would be able to lookup from an array or blob with ease but that doesn't seem to be the case. As such it sounds like I should probably change my approach and have the script run the photolist() script putting the values to a sheet and then upon completion of that script trigger a vlookup in my workbook that looks up the values from the photolist.